# Как загрузить файлы с сайта сразу на сервер?

Tags: wget

Как скачать файлы с сайта на сервер если этот сайт например (Themeforest) где для скачивания нужно залогиниться на сайте а потом уже можно качать? Варианты с FTP не подходят так как сначала скачать на свой комп а потом уже на сервер не охота

Comment: И Wget, и FTP-клиент можно запустить прямо на сервере без своего компа

Comment: понятно что у сервера есть FTP клиент, но как ты с помощью FTP скачаешь файл  с сайта, которого я привел как пример.

Answer (score 0):

Через обычный wget вряд ли получится подделать авторизацию (возможно вру, пусть сообщество поправит если кто-то знает как это сделать). Как вариант можно использовать curl (или любой другой инструмент, который умеет в отправку запросов) и эмулировать авторизацию на сайте. Лучше всего написать какой-то скрипт, а не выполнять такое из консоли ибо колхоз.

Т.е ваша последовательность действий должна быть примерно такой:

1. Проанализируйте как сайт выполняет авторизацию и до какого момента считает пользователя авторизованным. Это может быть передача токена в cookie или header или что-то другое, специфичное. Так же полезным будет узнать: Как долго длится сессия авторизации и при каких условиях разлогинивает. Если это обработать, то ваш скрипт не упрется в ошибку, если его разлогинит. Универсального способа как подстроится под авторизацию тут нет, придется поиграться.
2. Сохранить данные полученные в пункте 1.
3. Проанализировать запрос на загрузку документа с сервера, нужно знать какие данные сайт подставляет в запросе. Часто нужны только данные авторизации, но сайт может добавлять какие-то специфичные параметры.
4. Подставляете данные полученные данные в запрос и загружаете